# PHP doesn't accept <?

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I have a little problem. After installed xampp on localhost I saw, that my PHP doesn't accept `<?`. When I have only `<?` it will show me error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in **D:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php on line 1113**.

On my web server it works well. But when I replace `<?` to `<?php`, it works on localhost too. I have a lot of files with just a `<?` and don't have enough time to replace every `<?`. Is here any way to allow only `<?` on localhost?

Comment: look up "short opening PHP tags"

Comment: You have shorttags disabled. Most hosting services have this off by default also. It is best to adjust your code to use the normal <?php decalration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is not full, but if i understood correctly, it's not accepting the <?php

you can change the behavior in `php.ini ---> short_opentag=On`

but my advice is to always use the `<?php tag`.
sorry if this is not what you are asking for but this is what I understood from the title of the question.

Answer (score 1):

you probably have to check your php.ini there is one parameter `short_open_tag` tells php to recognize `<?` as php code beginning tag or not, here is some more information about this param:

[php.net:ini.short-open-tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing the pain of [short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).

Your best bet is to stop using them as you might end up using hosting which has them turned on in the future.

You can [configure PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) to support them if you really want to though.